# Canvas animation with JavaScript. Random coordinates and speed at every initiation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

**Edited :** Thanks to all for valuable time and effort. Finally I made this )) [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/35/)

I was just playing with canvas and made this. Fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/).

```
... some code here ...

var cords = [];

for(var i = 50; i <= width; i += 100) {
  for(var j = 50; j <= height; j += 100) {
    cords.push({ cor: i+','+j});
  }
}

console.log(cords);

var offset = 15,
    speed = 0.01,
    angle = 0.01;

cords.forEach(function(e1) {
  e1.base = parseInt(Math.random()*25);
  e1.rgb = 'rgb('+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+')';
});

setInterval(function() {
  cords.forEach(function(e1) {
    e1.base = parseInt(Math.random()*25);
    e1.rgb = 'rgb('+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+')';
  });
},5000);

function render() {

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

  cords.forEach(function(e1) {
    //console.log(e1);
    ctx.fillStyle = e1.rgb;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var r = e1.base + Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)) * offset;
    var v = e1.cor.split(',');
    ctx.arc(v[0],v[1],r,0,Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  });
  angle += speed;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

Was wondering if -

1. Coordinates can be made random, now they are fixed as you can see. After 5000 mil, balls will show up in various random cords but even at their fullest they won't touch each other.
2. Every ball has same speed for changing size, I want that to be different too. Meaning, After 5000 mil, they show up with different animation speeds as well.

Also any suggestion on improving code and making it better/quicker/lighter is much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: define speed and angle in the circles object themselves https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/5/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks but I wanted cords to be random at every init. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/6/)

Comment: Well just add it. That was just a comment to let you know the basics of how to deal with the general problem. Now you know it, you can add any singular property to your objects.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - See it running [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/6/).

### Making the coordinates random:

This requires you to add some random displacement to the x and y coordinates. So I added a random value to the coordinates. But then a displacement of less than 1 is not noticeable. So you'd need to magnify that random number by a multiplier. That's where the `randomizationFactor` comes in. I have set it to `100` since that is the value by which you shift the coordinates in each iteration. So that gives a truly random look to the animation.

### Making Speed Random:

This one took me a while to figure out, but the ideal way is to push a value of speed into the array of coordinates. This let's you ensure that for the duration of animation, the speed will remain constant and that gives you a smoother feel. But again multiplying the radius `r` with a value between 0 and 1 reduces the speed significantly for some of the circles. So I have added a multiplier to 3 to compensate slightly for that.

Ideally I'd put a 2, as the average value of `Math.random()` is 0.5, so a multiplier of 2 would be adequate to compensate for that. But a little experimentation showed that the multiplier of 3 was much better. You can choose the value as per your preference.

Your logic of generating the coordinates changes as follows:

```
for(var i = 50; i <= width;i += 100)  {
  for(var j = 51; j <= height;j += 100) {
    var x = i + (Math.random() - 0.5)*randomizationFactor;
    var y = j + (Math.random() - 0.5)*randomizationFactor;
    cords.push({ cor: x+','+y, speed: Math.random()});
  }
}
```

Your logic of enlarging the circles changes as follows:

```
function render() {

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

  cords.forEach(function(e1) {
    //console.log(e1);
    ctx.fillStyle = e1.rgb;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var r = e1.base + Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)) * offset * e1.speed * 3;
    var v = e1.cor.split(',');
    ctx.arc(v[0],v[1],r,0,Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  });
  angle += speed ;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

### Suggestion: Update the coordinates with color

I'd probably also update the location of circles every 5 seconds along with the colors. It's pretty simple to do as well. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/10/) I've just created a function `resetCoordinates` that runs every 5 seconds along with the `setBaseRgb` function.

```
var cords = [];
function resetCoordinates() {
  cords = [];

  for(var i = 50; i <= width;i += 100)  {
    for(var j = 51; j <= height;j += 100) {
      var x = i + (Math.random() - 0.5)*randomizationFactor;
      var y = j + (Math.random() - 0.5)*randomizationFactor;
      cords.push({ cor: x+','+y, speed: Math.random()});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One thing, the balls are overlapping one another. How can we prevent that. Everything else is cool!

Comment: One of the ways to do that would be to keep the randomizationFactor slightly smaller, and the speed multiplier smaller (as I mentioned). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/11/) I have kept them 50 and 1.5 respectively, and the balls rarely touch each other. The other way of achieving the same effect would be calculate if the balls would touch each other or not and then modify their coordinates to avoid that. But that seems too tedious to me.

Comment: Very right. Looking at it, if one ball is getting pretty big, there is a good chance of overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** I did some fixes in your code that can make your animation more dynamic. Totally rewritten sample.
*(sorry for variable name changing, imo now better)*

Built in `Math.random` not really random, and becomes obvious when you meet animations. Try to use this [random-js](https://github.com/ckknight/random-js) lib.

```
var randEngine = Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed();
var rand = function(from, to){
  return Random.integer(from, to)(randEngine)
}
```

Internal base properties to each circle would be better(more dynamic).

```
var circles = [];

// better to save coords as object neither as string
for(var i = 50; i <= width; i += 100)
  for(var j = 50; j <= height; j += 100)
   circles.push({ 
    coords: {x:i,y:j}
   });
```

We can adjust animation with new bouncing property.

```
var offset = 15,
    speed = 0.005,
    angle = 0.01,
    bouncing = 25;
```

This is how `setBaseRgb` function may look like

```
function setBaseRgb(el){
  el.base = rand(-bouncing, bouncing);
  el.speed = rand(5, 10) * speed;
  el.angle = 0;
  el.rgb = 'rgb('+rand(0, 255)+','+rand(0, 255)+','+rand(0, 255)+')';
}
```

All your animations had fixed `setInterval` timeout. Better with random timeout.

```
cords.forEach(function(el){
  // random timeout for each circle
  setInterval(setBaseRgb.bind(null,el), rand(3000, 5000));
})
```

You forgot to add your base to your circle position

```
function render() {    

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

  circles.forEach(function(el) {
    ctx.fillStyle = el.rgb;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var r = bouncing + el.base + Math.abs(Math.sin(el.angle)) * offset;
    var coords = el.coords;
    ctx.arc(
       coords.x + el.base,
       coords.y + el.base,
       r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false
    );
    ctx.fill();
    el.angle += el.speed;
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

**Effect 1** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/31/)

Adding this

```
if(el.angle > 1)
  el.angle=0;
```

Results **bubling** effect

**Effect 2** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/33/)

Playing with formulas results this

**Effect 3** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/34/)

Comment: I liked the thought of breaking the process of updating all balls at once! It looks quite interesting.

Comment: Yes it is interesting! Totally different view. Thank you! But cords are the same. I like them changed. Not same row and column again and again. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll try to fix it now.

Comment: So cool. How can we change size factor to stop overlapping. Like https://jsfiddle.net/v9x1gpLq/11/

Comment: Great! we can push this to some github project as background animation.

Comment: Haha .. Question: Does windows provide any way to use something like this, something live, as desktop wallpaper or background lol

Comment: Windows? haha no. I meant background animation in website headers, it is popular nowadays.